# Extract string from data

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to catch these strings (C011A1CC) beginning with **7E03** and ending with **80** in this data string

```
string value = "7E 03 C0 11 A1 CC 80 7E 03 C0 20 A1 CC 80 7E 03 C0 31 A1 CC 80 7E 03 C0 41 A1 CC 80";
string newValue = value.Trim();
string noSpacecStr = value.Replace(" ", "");

 Match m = Regex.Match(noSpacecStr, @"\b7E03");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        string key = m.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

In instance, I have to get this value (C0 11 A1 CC) between 7E03 and 80 but these data blocks not included (Regex, Regular Expression) 
=> 7E 03 (C0 11 A1 CC) 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `"7E03((..)*?)80"`. The `(..)*?` part makes sure you take multiples of 2, and the shortest possible option.